# Find pattern only until first occurrence of another pattern (or: how to remove random effects from a formula of mixed effects models)

Tags: r, regex, lme4

I want to extract information from model formulas, especially I want to remove random effects to just get the "fixed effects part" from mixed models (lme4-notation).

To do this, I search for the last `+` in the formula before a paranthesis `(` is found. Everything until the `+` must be the "fixed" part of the formula. This works fine for models with fixed effects predictors / variables.

However, for null-models (intercept-only in the fixed effects), there might be no `+`, e.g. if the formula is `Reaction ~ (Days | Subject)`. In this case, I check if there is *no* `+`-sign. But this does not work for models with *multiple* random parts. In the below examples, the `grepl()`for `f2` should return `FALSE`, but returns `TRUE`, because the `+` is found for the *second* opening paranthesis in the random parts.

My question: How can I stop checking for `+` after the first `(`, so that a possible second or third random effect term is ignored? The goal is for the below example that the `grepl()`-commands return `FALSE`, `FALSE`, `TRUE`, `TRUE`.

```
f1 <- "Reaction ~ (1 + Days | Subject)"
f2 <- "Reaction ~ (1 | mygrp/mysubgrp) + (1 | Subject)"
f3 <- "Reaction ~ x1 + x2 + (1 + Days | Subject)"
f4 <- "Reaction ~ x1 + x2 + (1 | mygrp/mysubgrp) + (1 | Subject)"

# works!
grepl("\\+(\\s)*\\((.*)\\)", f1) # should return FALSE
#> [1] FALSE

# fails...
grepl("\\+(\\s)*\\((.*)\\)", f2) # should return FALSE
#> [1] TRUE

# works!
grepl("\\+(\\s)*\\((.*)\\)", f3) # should return TRUE
#> [1] TRUE

# works!
grepl("\\+(\\s)*\\((.*)\\)", f4) # should return TRUE
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: By the way: Can anyone elaborate why  `grepl("\\~[:space:]*[:alnum:]+[:space:]*\\+", f3)` returns `FALSE` and `stringr::str_detect(f3, "\\~[:space:]*[:alnum:]+[:space:]*\\+")` returns `TRUE`?

Comment: @Roman: Try `grepl("\\~[[:space:]]*[[:alnum:]]+[[:space:]]*\\+", f3)`

Comment: FFS. @AkselA Thank you. I thought I was going insane.

Comment: @Roman: No, just R being its idiosyncratic self. ;)

Comment: As the question ended up not being much about pattern matching, It might be appropriate to change the title, so other people trying to remove random effects from formulae can find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really answering your question from a RE perspective (for which there likely is an answer), but if your goal is to extract the random effects and/or fixed effect formula's you might gain more from looking at the source code of `glFormula` and `lFormula` form the `lme4` package itself. As they are creating both the design matrix `X` and `Z` for fixed and random effects respectively, they will have to extract their individual parts at some points.

For example, to extract the fixed effects the function `nobars` and `RHSForm` are used:

```
library(lme4)
f1 <- Reaction ~ (1 + Days | Subject)
f2 <- Reaction ~ (1 | mygrp/mysubgrp) + (1 | Subject)
f3 <- Reaction ~ x1 + x2 + (1 + Days | Subject)
f4 <- Reaction ~ x1 + x2 + (1 | mygrp/mysubgrp) + (1 | Subject)
(f1FixedEffects <- nobars(lme4:::RHSForm(f1)) #note the triple 'lme4:::'. RHSForm is not exported to the public environment.
[1] 1
(f2FixedEffects <- nobars(lme4:::RHSForm(f2))
[1] 1
(f1FixedEffects <- nobars(lme4:::RHSForm(f3))
x1 + x2
(f1FixedEffects <- nobars(lme4:::RHSForm(f4))
x1 + x2
```

If the desire is to extract the entire formula you can use

```
lme4:::RHSForm(f1) <- nobars(lme4:::RHSForm(f1)
f1
Reaction ~ 1
```

or similar (thanks to AkselA for his comment)

```
nobars(f1)
Reaction ~ 1
```

for the fixed effects.

Note that i converted your string formulas to formulas. This could also just be done with 'as.formula()'

Comment: I think you can use `nobars()` on the formula straight, without isolating the righthand side.

Comment: Indeed, that is true. Simply ended up copying from the source, without thinking. I'll edit my answer making a note of that, thank you. :-)

Comment: Thanks! Just looked at the code, and just saw that `nobars()` simply iteratively calls itself again with the second part of the formula (from the original third part). So what `nobars()` in the end does, is `f4[[3]][[2]][[2]]` (add arbitrary amount of `[[2]]` for each further random effect).

Comment: @Daniel: I saw that as well, calls the recursive function `nobars_()` which scans the tree for `|`s. Pretty neat.

Answer (score 2):

Oliver's answer is correct, especially as you're already using `lme4`, but there is also a `base` framework for modifying formulae that can be used.

```
# Is read as class formula
f4 <- Reaction ~ x1 + x2 + (1 | mygrp/mysubgrp) + (1 | Subject)

# Isolate the terms and find which contains a vertical bar
f4t <- terms(f4)
dr <- grep("|", labels(f4t), fixed=TRUE)

# Drop the term(s) containing a vertical bar
f4td <- drop.terms(f4t, dr)

# Update the old formula with the new set of terms
f4u <- update(f4, f4td)

# Voilà
f4u
# Reaction ~ x1 + x2
```

As mentioned in the comments, this will fail in two particular cases: all effects are random, and no effects are random. To handle these exceptions properly I found it best to write a proper function while I'm at it.

```
drop_randfx <- function(form) {
    form.t <- terms(form)
    dr <- grepl("|", labels(form.t), fixed=TRUE)
    if (mean(dr) == 1) {
        form.u <- update(form, . ~ 1)
    } else {
        if (mean(dr) == 0) {
            form.u <- form
        } else {
            form.td <- drop.terms(form.t, which(dr))
            form.u <- update(form, form.td)
        }
    }
    form.u
}
```

This passes all the tests

```
f1 <- Reaction ~ (1 + Days | Subject)
f2 <- Reaction ~ (1 | mygrp/mysubgrp) + (1 | Subject)
f3 <- Reaction ~ x1 + x2 + (1 + Days | Subject)
f4 <- Reaction ~ x1 * x2 + (1 | mygrp/mysubgrp) + (1 | Subject)
f5 <- Reaction ~ x1 + x2

sapply(list(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5), drop_randfx)    # [[1]]

# [[1]]
# Reaction ~ 1
# 
# [[2]]
# Reaction ~ 1
# 
# [[3]]
# Reaction ~ x1 + x2
# 
# [[4]]
# Reaction ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2
# 
# [[5]]
# Reaction ~ x1 + x2
```

Comment: Though I like this answer because it relies on base R, I accepted the answer by Oliver because it also works for `f1` and `f2`. `drop.terms()` fails here, maybe this exception can be captured somehow.